# How to refer to Git commit SHA-1 when I accidentally have similarly named tag?

Tags: git

I made a mistake while creating an annotated tag and ended up with a tag named `c696e99` (that is, I accidentally used the start of the SHA-1 of the commit I was trying to tag as the name of the tag instead of giving it as the commit to tag). While I was fixing the problem by creating an another tag *before* I would remove the accidentally created tag, I noticed that while I try to create a new tag with the correct syntax

```
git tag -a the-name-of-the-tag-I-meant-to-use c696e99
```

Git says

```
warning: refname 'c696e99' is ambiguous.
hint: You have created a nested tag. The object referred to by your new tag is
hint: already a tag. If you meant to tag the object that it points to, use:
hint: 
hint:   git tag -f test-tag c696e99^{}
```

This is obviously result of Git seeing `c696e99` as potential reference to commit SHA-1 or the tag name. And it selects the tag name as the effective target which is not what I want.

If I were trying to refer to branch or tag I would simply add prefix `refs/heads/` or `refs/tags/` and continue. However, **how to tell Git that I'm trying to refer to the commit hash with the given string when it fully matches a tag name?**

Note that I don't want to refer to the commit pointed by the tag called "c696e99" but the commit with the SHA-1 starting with "c696e99". The hint that Git gives me tells how to refer to the commit that the tag points so that's not the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

After trial and error I found that the if input is exactly 40 character long hexadecimal string, `git` will *always* interpret it as SHA-1 string. As such, I could write

```
git tag -a the-name-of-the-tag-I-meant-to-use $(git rev-parse --disambiguate=c696e9)
```

However, that seems like a pretty messy solution. I'm adding this answer so that there's at least one solution in case nothing better is known. And note that this would fail if the `rev-parse` finds more than one matching revisions so this solution assumes that the prefix match identifies exactly one commit SHA-1.

Comment: If the tag is not pushed yet, it should be safe to be deleted (`git tag -d`), resolving the `rev-parse` (or any other potential) issue. Otherwise, deleting it would not guarantee an error-free repo for anyone who might have fetched in the meantime, which makes this a judgement call (a bit like `push -f`, but I found the side-effects for forced tags are usually less expected).

Comment: Good point. I wanted to keep the incorrectly created tag available until the replacement is ready because I wanted to re-use the annotated contents.